# How to take screenshot, when app does not allow to do it?

Tags: screenshots

My education app does not app me to take screenshot when I play video on it. So can you please tell me , there is any to take out the screenshot.

Comment: Video Frame Grabbers...

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the Screenshot Security, a solution would be Video Frame Grabbers ... I use PhotoEditor   [GooglePlay Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iudesk.android.photo.editor&hl=en_US)

Steps to grab that Video Frame ( Screenshot )

- Open Photo Editor App

[image: 1]

- Go To Tools

[image: 2]

- Go To Video Capture

[image: 3]

- Open The Video

[image: 4]

- Capture Frame

[image: 5]

If it is a protected video from Google Play or online, you need to use a different method.

- Online

> ADM ( Advanced Download Manager )

- Google Play

> Requires root access to pull the video from /data/data/